# Method of Undetermined Coefficients reasoning

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So this method is used to find a particular solution for higher order non homogenous linear differential equations. My problem is, it involves guesswork and hasn't got a solid proof. My textbook tries to explain it, and tries to give one a working understanding, but doesn't really help. 
If somebody could explain the method in a clear way, that'd be great.

Comment: Please give an example or two of such "guesswork".

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx